# how to show a div under selected text field

Tags: html, datepicker, tooltip

i don't need any calender, datepicker, or timepicker.. i just want to know...

Can somebody please tell me... how the divs come to appear when user clicks on some specific text fields...

see on this link..
http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

i dont' want to show calendar or time picker.. but may be some images with some details.. that is not a part of question.. i just want to show some div with "blabla" data...

### Thank you

Oh.. i found it..

I got it.. in jquery i found a method of "offset();" that further give me its' left and top values..
.. Thank You

ALHAMDULILLAH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best way I can think of is to use JQuery and generate the div on the fly when your element is clicked.

The div should be absolutely positioned and set to display: none (if you want the slide down effect). This is a quick sample I made for showing the div:

```
$('.moreInfo').click(function(){
  var data = "Whatever data you want to show in the div";
  var div = $('<div />').text(data)
                        .css('display', 'none')
                        .css('position', 'absolute')
                        .css('top', $(this).outerHeight() + $(this).offset().top)
                        .css('left', $(this).position().left)
                        .css('width', '200px')
                        .css('height', '300px')
                        .css('border', '1px solid #000');
  $(this).after(div);
  div.slideDown(500);
});
```

(The CSS may as well be a separate CSS-rule and modified however you want, except for the 'top' and 'left' attributes)

This opens a new div for every click, so you probably want to check if the div already exists and then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to define functions for the input field on focus and blur:

```
<input id="sampleInput" type="text" onfocus="showDiv()" onblur="hideDiv()" />
<div id="content" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;visible:false;">...</div>
```

EDIT: Here's some psuedocode to get you started

```
//This will give you the distance from the top of the page to the input box
inputTop =  inputElement.offsetTop;     

//This will give yout he height of the input element    
inputHeight = inputElement.offsetHeight;

//Now set the top of the content div to be the sum of the offsets:
contentDiv.style.top = inputTop + inputHeight;

//Now show the content div
contentDiv.style.visible = "true";
```

Comment: @zohoGorganzola... but how will that specific div will be on the same position where i clicked..????

Comment: @MFarooqi I added some psuedocode to give you an example of how to position the element relative to the input field